# CRC calculation wrong output

Tags: vb6, crc

I am trying to figure out a CRC check for a serial controlled device.
I have an example, when I send this example to the device, it responds correctly.

This is the complete serial string which the device responds to:

```
\x00\x17\x3d\x30\x32\x32\x30\x39\x39\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x37\x34\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x01\x28
```

(The last 2 bytes (`\x01\x28`) are the CRC outcomes).

This is my code:

```
Dim Send As String
Dim CRC1 As String
Dim CRC2 As String
Dim TEMP As String

Private Sub Command1_Click()

Send = &H0 & &H17 & "=" & "022" & "099" & "00" & "00" & "0000074" & "00000"

CRC1 = &H0
CRC2 = &H0
TEMP = &H0

For i = 1 To Len(Send)
    TEMP = CRC1
    CRC1 = CRC2 Xor Asc(Mid$(Send, i, 1))
    CRC2 = TEMP
   
Next i

Text1.Text = "CRC1= " & CRC1 & " / CRC2= " & CRC2

End Sub
```

The output should be: `CRC1 = 1` (decimal) and `CRC2 = 40` (decimal)
But I am getting `51`/`60`.

I think is has something to do with datatypes.

This is the original CRC formula from the device:

```
Set <CRC1> and <CRC2> to zero.
For every <CHAR> in <MSG> do
<TEMP> = <CRC1>
<CRC1> = <CRC2> XOR <CHAR>
<CRC2> = <TEMP>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just entered your data (`00173d30323230393930303030303030303037343030303030`) on https://crccalc.com/ to check if *any* CRC algorithm arrives at `\x01\x28`, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @tomalak - possibly because that algo doesn't seem to perform a *cyclic* redundancy check, but a *longitudinal* one. And I don't see how it could produce a 16-bit value, given 8-bit characters

Answer (score 2):

You should have looked at your string `Send` to make sure that it's what you wanted. It isn't. Its construction needs to be:

`Send = Chr(&H0) & Chr(&H17) &` ...

Then you get the answer you're looking for.

By the way, the thing you are computing is not in any way a CRC. Whoever wrote that formula had no idea what they were talking about. What they constructed is a lousy check value algorithm, so they also had no idea what they were doing.